# Adding an image background to a radar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm doing a Data analysis project for my statistics Laboratory class, where I have to analyse some data set. I chose a pokemon [data set](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ulrikthygepedersen/pokemon-stats), and so far it's been going smoothly.

I decided to use a radar chart to show the average stat distribuition per type, and it worked like intended:

[image: Average Ice type stat distribuition (it's in portuguese)]

But then I had the idea to add the types icon to the radar chart to make it look better. I searched up how to add images to plots and added it to my code.

But when I ran it the image was very distorted:

[image: radar chart with the ice type icon]

[image: the icon I wanted as the background]

```py
statsLabel = ['HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Attack', 'Sp. Defense', 'Speed']
stats = [77, 83, 77, 74, 77, 66]
angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(statsLabel), endpoint=False)
angles = np.concatenate((angles, [angles[0]]))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_ylim(0, 110)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
stats = np.concatenate((stats, [stats[0]]))  
ax.plot(angles, stats ,linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="First Set")  
ax.fill(angles, stats, alpha=0.1)
ax.set_thetagrids(angles[:-1] * 180/np.pi, statsLabel)
for angle, value in zip(angles, stats):
        ax.text(angle, value+10, str(value))
plt.title('Stats do tipo Ice')
file = "Ice_icon_SwSh.png"
img = plt.imread(file)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I wanted the type icon to be inside the circumference, with some transparancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to add the image as an AnnotationBox.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from matplotlib.artist import Artist

statsLabel = ['HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Attack', 'Sp. Defense', 'Speed']
stats = [77, 83, 77, 74, 77, 66]

angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(statsLabel), endpoint=False)
angles = np.concatenate((angles, [angles[0]]))
stats = np.concatenate((stats, [stats[0]]))  

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_ylim(0, 110)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.plot(angles, stats, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="First Set")  
ax.fill(angles, stats, alpha=0.1)
ax.set_thetagrids(angles[:-1] * 180/np.pi, statsLabel)
for angle, value in zip(angles, stats):
    ax.text(angle, value + 10, str(value))

file = "Ice_icon_SwSh.png"
img = plt.imread(file)
imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=2.2, alpha=0.3)  # You can change the zoom to adjust the displayed image size
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0.5, 0.5), frameon=False, xycoords='axes fraction', boxcoords="axes fraction")
ax.add_artist(ab)
Artist.set_zorder(ab, -10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html) to do this. For example (adapting your code above):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

statsLabel = ['HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Attack', 'Sp. Defense', 'Speed']
stats = [77, 83, 77, 74, 77, 66]

angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(statsLabel), endpoint=False)
angles = np.concatenate((angles, [angles[0]]))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

stats = np.concatenate((stats, [stats[0]]))
ax.plot(angles, stats ,linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="First Set")
ax.fill(angles, stats, alpha=0.1)
ax.set_thetagrids(angles[:-1] * 180/np.pi, statsLabel)
for angle, value in zip(angles, stats):
    ax.text(angle, value+10, str(value))

# create inset axis (origin at 0, 0 and with height and width of 1
# and use zorder to set behind current axes)
axins = ax.inset_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], polar=False, zorder=-10)

img = plt.imread("Ice_icon_SwSh.png")

# add image with transparency
axins.imshow(img, alpha=0.3)

# remove axes spines
axins.spines[["right", "left", "bottom", "top"]].set_visible(False)
axins.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)
axins.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=False)
axins.set_xticks([])
axins.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

which (for me) produces:

[image]